# Specifying headers in Chromecast Receiver

Tags: cookies, header, media-player, chromecast, receiver

The API that I'm using to retrieve media payload from requires an authentication header to be specified. Right now, I'm simply setting the cookies of the documents then getting the content because this seems to be the easiest way.

I ran into issues with cookies since cookies are domain specific and I'm hosting the receiver file in Google Drive instead of the domain that points to the API endpoints, I needed to set up proxy servers which would overwrite the cookies midway before the requests reach the endpoints.

This is an extremely complicated way of authentication. Does anyone know how I can specify header in the receiver file?

Comment: I recommend checking out [CORS](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#cors) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @not_a_bot Thanks for the response. That is the approach I've gone with.